# Production.py issue with deployment of cookiecutter-django and gunicorn to digital ocean

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, digital-ocean, cookiecutter-django

I built a Django project using the latest version of [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django), which seems to be working fine on my local computer as well as when I run it through `python manage.py runserver` using the various settings files. I'm trying to test my Gunicorn server on Digital Ocean (running Ubuntu 16.04) but for some reason can't get the server to run properly when `production.py` is the one being used.

When I do the following command on bash:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.test --preload config.wsgi
```

everything works fine and I get these:

```
[2018-02-18 23:31:14 -0500] [31662] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2018-02-18 23:31:14 -0500] [31662] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (31662)
[2018-02-18 23:31:14 -0500] [31662] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-02-18 23:31:14 -0500] [31666] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31666
```

But when I don't specify the settings file and default to `production.py` with `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --preload config.wsgi`, where the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is set to `config.settings.production`, I only get these:

```
DEBUG 2018-02-18 23:31:55,786 base 31681 140442914699008 Configuring Raven for host: <raven.conf.remote.RemoteConfig object at 0x7fbb5cc0b668>
INFO 2018-02-18 23:31:55,786 base 31681 140442914699008 Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.
```

And it pretty much just gets stuck there. What might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was an SSL problem. By default, cookiecutter-django forces HTTPS but my server doesn't yet have any certificates so it was failing. I added the following section to the `~/.bashrc` file and it worked:

```
## for testing 
export DJANGO_DEBUG=False (can be True when testing)
export DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=True (can be False when testing)
```